# Faster Way of Getting Text from Image

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract and OpenCV to read text from images. At the moment I take a screenshot, save to disk then extract the text. My code works ok but I am doing something that is time-critical so I wondered whether there is a better approach.

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('temp_chit.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)

end = timer()
print(end - start)
```